# Javascript copy contents of one object literal into another without reflecting changes in future?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I am trying to emulate html5 `sessionStorage` for browsers which don't support it. I am emulating the `sessionStorage` object as a object literal, and I am checking to see if it has changed by storing both an old version of the `sessionStorage` object as well as a new one. However, if I directly make the "old" copy of `sessionStorage` directly equal to the `sessionStorage` object itself, if the object `sessionStorage` gets changed, it will reflect those changes on the "old" copy as well. How do I copy the object literal without it reflecting the changes in the future? An example of the code that is not working is at http://jsfiddle.net/pkXXC/1. Clicking the button will update the `sessionStorage` object. 
The results are logged in the console.
**Note: You must be using internet explorer 7.0 or below for the example to work.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a "deep copy".  Google has plenty of examples, and there's one in jQuery - `$.extend(true, ...)`

Comment: @papirtiger FWIW I wouldn't actually copy jQuery's implementation as it has a lot of capabilities that aren't needed in this case.  However if you already have jQuery loaded, there's not much point rolling another implementation.

Comment: I was not suggesting he copy it, however it is an extremely good example that ovoids alot of the possible pitfalls with JS loops and prototype properties.